# Como limpiar pantalla y volver a pedir datos por teclado en c++ IF ELSE

Tags: c++

estoy estudiando c++, tengo el siguiente programa, funciona pero me gustaría que no se cerrara.

```
//Ficha 4a
/*pregunta dos números, que operación deseas hacer y muestra resultado*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()

{

double a, b;
int c;

cout << "Introduzca el primer número " << endl ;
cin >> a;
cout << "Introduzca el segundo número" << endl ;
cin >> b;
cout << "Que operación deseas hacer, 1(suma), 2(producto) , 3 (division), 4 (resta)/n" ;
cin >> c;


if (c==1) {
cout <<"el resultado de suma es:"<<a+b<<endl;
}

if (c==2) {
cout <<"el resultado de producto es:"<<a*b<<endl;
}

if (c==3) {
cout <<"el resultado de division es:"<<a/b<<endl;
}

if (c==4) {
cout <<"el resultado de resta es:"<<a-b<<endl;
}


return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Answer (score 1):

La forma es implementando un bucle que te permita el ingreso de los datos nuevamente. En mi caso puse las opciones primero, ya que agregue la opcion 5 que significa salir del ciclo para que tu programa finalice.  El bucle en mi ejemplo es   while (c!=5) mientras esta condición sea verdadera el programa continuará ejecutándose.

```
//Ficha 4a
/*pregunta dos números, que operación deseas hacer y muestra resultado*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()

{

double a, b;
int c;

cout << "Que operación deseas hacer, 1(suma), 2(producto) , 3 (division), 4 (resta), 5(salir)/n" ;
cin >> c;

while (c!=5)
{


       cout << "Introduzca el primer número " << endl ;
       cin >> a;
       cout << "Introduzca el segundo número" << endl ;
       cin >> b;

       if (c==1) {
          cout <<"el resultado de suma es:"<<a+b<<endl;
       }

       if (c==2) {
          cout <<"el resultado de producto es:"<<a*b<<endl;
           }

       if (c==3) {
          cout <<"el resultado de division es:"<<a/b<<endl;
         }

      if (c==4) {
          cout <<"el resultado de resta es:"<<a-b<<endl;
        }

cout << "Que operación deseas hacer, 1(suma), 2(producto) , 3 (division), 4 (resta), 5(salir)/n" ;
cin >> c;
}
return 0 ;
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando.

[Ejemplo](https://onlinegdb.com/ByJVgMi_f)

Comment: En realidad la solucion mas correcta seria usar un do while, ya que necesitas que el codigo se ejecute una vez siempre, y de esa forma no repites una parte del codigo inecesariamente.

Comment: De todas formas la parte que se repite del código es infima (solo es la operación) y la pregunta entiendo a apuntaba a actualizar el campo de comparación del bucle que es lo importante de la pregunta.

Comment: No importa si es infima o no. Es una mejor solucion y mas correcta.

Comment: gbianchi como estamos..... ja ja ja. igualmente el user hizo lo que quizo... tomo el while le puso un switch.... l

Comment: suena pesado.. pero si hay una solucion un poco mejor, porque no aplicarla ;)

Comment: y no te preocupes, que le estoy pegando (correctamente) a todas por igual...

Comment: Todo bien... gbianchi... usted sabra... lo que me comentas yo ya lo se, pero estan bien que lo sepan otros.

Comment: Muchas Gracias a Todos :)

Answer (score 1):

Ya que quieres volver a repetir los datos, entonces lo más conveniente es utilizar un bucle `do-while` que te garantizará que los datos se pidan al menos una vez.

Por otro lado, lo siguiente se ve medio feo: `"Que operación deseas hacer, 1(suma), 2(producto) , 3 (division), 4 (resta)/n" ;` además de que al final debe ser `\n` en lugar de `/n`. En estos casos es mejor crear un menú de opciones del siguiente modo:

```
cout << "Que operacion deseas hacer?\n";
cout << "1. Suma\n";
cout << "2. Producto\n";
cout << "3. Division\n";
cout << "4. Resta\n";
```

A su vez, cuando el usuario seleccione una opción, procedemos a validarla haciendo uso de otro `do-while` de la siguiente manera:

```
do {
    cout << "Seleccione una de las opciones anteriores:\t";
    cin >> opcion; 

    if (opcion <= 0 || opcion > 4)
        cout << "ERROR. La opcion no existe.\n";
} while (opcion <= 0 || opcion > 4);
```

A propósito, he cambiado la variable `c`, que no me dice nada, por la variable `opcion`, ya que la última es mucho más clara en su significado. Recuerda que los programas deben estar escritos de la manera más legible posible.

Finalmente, lo de los `if` esta bien... en principio. Tú lógica funciona, peero es siempre es mejor hacer algo que sea más óptimo. En este caso, es mejor hacer uso de la estructura de control selectiva `switch`. La sintaxis es bastante sencilla, cada `if(...)` se convertirá en un `case`.

De manera más concreta tenemos lo siguiente:

```
switch(opcion)
{
    case 1: {
        cout << "El resultado de suma es:\t" << num1 + num2 << '\n';
    } break;

    case 2: {
        cout << "El resultado de producto es:\t" << num1 * num2 << '\n';
    } break;

    case 3: {
        cout << "El resultado de division es:\t" << num1 / num2 << '\n'; 
    } break;

    case 4: {
        cout << "El resultado de resta es:\t" << num1 - num2 << '\n';
    } break;            
}
```

Aquí he vuelto a cambiar tus variables. En este caso `a` y `b` por las más descriptivas `num1` y `num2`. No necesitamos el `default` porque previamente hemos validado que las opciones estén en el rango `[1-4]`.

Esta parte de mi solución puede resultar un poco polémica, ya que en general ni yo mismo suelo usar y/o recomendar hacer uso de la función `system` (que está en la cabecera `<cstdlib>`), sin embargo, en un pequeño ejercicio como éste, no veo nada de malo. En cualquier caso, te recomiendo que leas el siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1107705/8781554) (en inglés).

Vamos a utilizar `system("cls")` que hará que la pantalla se limpie. Ya que el proceso es inmediato, no nos va a dar tiempo de ver el resultado de la operación escogida con nuestro par de números ingresados. Por eso, antes de limpiar la pantalla utilizo la función `Sleep` de la cabecera `<Windows.h>`. Esto tampoco es recomendado, debido a que no es multiplataforma. Como podrás deducir del nombre, lo anterior solo funciona en Windows. Hay una manera multiplataforma utilizando la función `sleep_for` de la cabecera `<thread>`  del estándar de C++, pero es algo un poco más complicado y no quiero hacer más complejo tu código.

Finalmente, todo el código con las modificaciones ya mencionadas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double num1, num2;
    int opcion; 

    do {        
        cout << "Introduzca el primer numero:\n";
        cin >> num1;
        cout << "Introduzca el segundo numero:\n";
        cin >> num2;

        cout << "Que operacion deseas hacer?\n";
        cout << "1. Suma\n";
        cout << "2. Producto\n";
        cout << "3. Division\n";
        cout << "4. Resta\n";   

        do {
            cout << "Seleccione una de las opciones anteriores:\t";
            cin >> opcion; 

            if (opcion <= 0 || opcion > 4)
                cout << "ERROR. La opcion no existe.\n";
        } while (opcion <= 0 || opcion > 4);

        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1: {
                cout << "El resultado de suma es:\t" << num1 + num2 << '\n';
            } break;

            case 2: {
                cout << "El resultado de producto es:\t" << num1 * num2 << '\n';
            } break;

            case 3: {
                cout << "El resultado de division es:\t" << num1 / num2 << '\n'; 
            } break;

            case 4: {
                cout << "El resultado de resta es:\t" << num1 - num2 << '\n';
            } break;            
        }
        Sleep(1000); //Puedes poner otro valor (esta función toma milisegundos)
        system("cls");                          
    } while (opcion != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Porque en lugar de un sleep, no haces una toma del teclado de cualquier cosa, de esa forma evitas el sleep.. y de paso que el usuario se tome el tiempo que quiera en ver que pasa.

Comment: @gbianchi uhmm no se me había ocurrido dicha idea (lo de usar `sleep` fue lo primero que se me vino a la mente). Su sugerencia me parece mejor ya que así se puede conseguir algo más multiplataforma, pero me da flojera cambiar el código xd. En todo caso, esperaré feedback del OP (si es que se anima a decir algo).

Answer (score -1):

Lo realicé con la función Switch, no se si sea más difícil de entender, ya que te encuentras estudiando, si gustas escribirme a mi correo **amaury.escobedo29@gmail.com**

```
// Importamos las librerias a utilizar
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // Una variable de tipo entero para poder controlar el switch
    int opc = 0;
    // 3 variables de tipo double, para resultados con puntos decimales
    // n1 - Variable que va a almacenar el digíto 1
    // n1 - Variable que va a almacenar el digíto 2
    // res - Variable que va a almacenar el resultado de la operación
    double n1, n2, res;
    // Ciclo While que controla el menú, así que cuando se precione el número 5 va a terminar el programa
    while(opc != 5)
    {
        // Imprimimos lo que se va a mostrar
        cout<<"Que operacion desea realizar"<<endl;
        cout<<"1. Suma"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Resta"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Multiplicacion"<<endl;
        cout<<"4. Division"<<endl;
        cout<<"5. Salir"<<endl;
        // Le decimos al usuario que digité un valor
        cout<<"Ingrese Opcion: ";
        // Guardamos el valor en la variable que va a controlar el elemento switch
        cin>>opc;

        // Condicional que se va a mostrar cada vez que no se digíte un valor deseado
        if(opc > 5)
        {
            cout<<"Ingresa una opcion Valida"<<endl; // Mensaje que se le va a mostrar al usuario
            system("cls"); // Comando para limpiar pantalla
        }

        // Switch que lleva como parametro la variable opc que tiene almacenado el valor ingresado por el ususario
        switch(opc)
        {
            // Si el usuario ingreso el valor 1
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Ingresa el Numero 1: ";
                cin>>n1;
                cout<<"Ingresa el Numero 2: ";
                cin>>n2;
                res = n1 + n2;
                cout<<"El resultado es: "<<res<<endl;
            break; // Palabra reservada que rompe la función que se le estableció y regresa al menú principal

            case 2:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Ingresa el Numero 1: ";
                cin>>n1;
                cout<<"Ingresa el Numero 2: ";
                cin>>n2;
                res = n1 - n2;
                cout<<"El resultado es: "<<res<<endl;
            break;

            case 3:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Ingresa el Numero 1: ";
                cin>>n1;
                cout<<"Ingresa el Numero 2: ";
                cin>>n2;
                res = n1 * n2;
                cout<<"El resultado es: "<<res<<endl;
            break;

            case 4:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Ingresa el Numero 1: ";
                cin>>n1;
                cout<<"Ingresa el Numero 2: ";
                cin>>n2;
                res = n1 / n2;
                cout<<"El resultado es: "<<res<<endl;
            break;

            case 5:
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Gracias por usar el programa :D"<<endl;
                cout<<"\t\tAdios"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esta solucion es mala comparada con otra de las que hay, que no repite casi nada de codigo innecesariamente.